# notification.confirm callback not firing phonegap iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova

I'm using Phonegap (Cordova) v1.9, and this app is solely for iPhone4+ use.

I've tried the two methods below, on their own and simultaneously.

Phonegap's `deviceready` event has been fired previous to this code.

I'm using the iPhone configuration utility to watch the console, but I'm not getting anything from the code below.

Also, I'm using Sencha Touch (v1.1) and jQuery. No conflicts noticed throughout the app.

Please help?

```
function onConfirmCallback(button){
    console.log("onConfirmCallback");
    console.log(button);
}

var toConfirm = navigator.notification.confirm("You don't have a pincode set.\nWould you like to set one now?", onConfirmCallback, "Pincode", "Yes,No");
toConfirm.onAlertDismissed = function(index, label){
    console.log("onAlertDismissed");
    console.log(index);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried looking for exceptions to see what might be happening?

```
try
{
    var toConfirm = navigator.notification.confirm("You don't have a pincode set.\nWould you like to set one now?", onConfirmCallback, "Pincode", "Yes,No");
    toConfirm.onAlertDismissed = function(index, label) {
        console.log("onAlertDismissed");
        console.log(index);
    }
}
catch (ex)
{
    console.log(ex.message);
}
```

**Edit:**

The example mentioned in the comment below (from https://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/126f56f4e296e555) is for PhoneGap 0.9.2. I have not seen any examples for v1.3 where the confirm function returns an object as your using with 'toConfirm'. Maybe that is causing your problem. Have you tried the following (removing all other code to do with `toConfirm` to simplify the problem)?

```
navigator.notification.confirm("You don't have a pincode set.\nWould you like to set one now?", onConfirmCallback, "Pincode", "Yes,No");
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm

Also, is there any reason your not using a newer version of PhoneGap (Cordova)?

Comment: nope I haven't, I'll try this out first thing in the morning and see if it sheds any light on the problem. The 'confirm' dialogue does show already though, so I assume the callback isn't being attached properly...but from what I can find online, my code above should do it.

Comment: Apparently the docs are incorrect, and that the call to confirm returns a delegate. https://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/126f56f4e296e555
I tried your `try{}catch(ex){}` example. Still nothing in my console. Any other ideas @JonWarnerNet ?

Comment: See edit, have you tried simplifying the problem? The example you gave from google groups is for PhoneGap 0.9.2.

Comment: Fair point on the version issue - I updated to v1.9. Turns out the problem was that I'm an idiot, and was editing the code in another (deeper down) part of the app, rather than the part that was being tested. Thank you very much for your help though!